# Installing Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I've used Ubuntu 14.04 for a bit and still know nothing about it. I can never find anything I understand about how to completely get rid of ubuntu so I can use windows 7. When I try to install the disk, all I get is error code 0x80070490 Windows setup can not find a place to store temporary installation files. To install windows, make sure that a partition on your boot disk has at least 692 MB of free space. I was hoping as a person who knows nothing about this OS could help me.

Comment: If you want to be a Ubuntu pro, you're better off trying lots of distros before actually installing them, and discover stuff online (optionally.)

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Put your Windows disc in.

**Step 2:** Go to BIOS.

**Step 3:** In boot options choose your disc to be booted first.

**Step 4:** Install Windows as you want.

Answer (score 0):

there is not enough blank space on the hard drive to store temporary files for installation. try lowering your system partion and then attempting the install. lower the partion by about 1gb and you should be fine.

If you do not know how to do that there are plenty of easy tutorials explaing how to change your partion file size. try searching google for that. Hope i could help.